# Run .ipa file on cross platform?

Tags: virtual-machine, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad Simulator (install ipa on pc)](https://superuser.com/questions/441987/ipad-simulator-install-ipa-on-pc)

My platforms are Linux and Windows.

Now I have a software whose extension is .ipa
I am looking for a way to run this file either on Windows or on Linux.

There exists  **Wine** which can run .exe files on Linux, similarly is there something which can run .ipa either on linux or windows??

I am also comfortable with getting into virtualization and emulation to get the software work!

Answer (score 0):

The only platform you can run a [.ipa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa) is Mac's OSX and you apple portable devices iOS

Comment: can i emulate something like this on linux or PC